# Best Way To Reduce Search Filters Until I Find A Document In MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a Collection of Documents structured like so:

```
{
name: "name1",
cost: 750,
weight: 75,
portable: true,
available: false
}
```

I want to find the first Document(s) that match the most preferences I am looking for. For instance if I searched for a match to this query:

```
{
name: "name1",
cost: 750,
weight: 80,
portable: true,
available: true
}
```

I want it to remove and re-add one property at a time and then two properties etc. at a time until it finds a match for the most properties possible.

```
{
name: "name1",
cost: 750,
portable: true
}
```

I am currently able to do that by creating an array of all the possible combinations

```
[["name"],["cost"],["weight"],["portable"],["available"],["name","cost"],["name", "weight"], etc...]
```

and then looping through the array and removing the properties that align with the values in each array and replacing them until I find a match.

This process works well, however the possible combinations go up exponentially the more Document properties exist, and in turn the code takes significantly longer to execute. I feel like there has to be a faster way(s) to find a match in MongoDB that I am not aware exists. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I don't think such functionality exists and is the task of MongoDB (as of v.4.2). With ElasticSearch, you might be able to get similar results if you assign scores to each field and set threshold on the score, so you might want sync your data with or migrate to ElasticSearch.

Comment: But if you want to do it in MongoDB I think you can cut down the number of combinations by process of elimination. You can count the number of the results for each fields, if any of them has 0 results, you can eliminate them in the next round, So in the next round if there is a tuple of fields that produced 0 results, you can eliminate the tuple, etc.

Comment: Thanks @thammada, I appreciate the suggestions. I will look down those paths!